# Determine a user's role, set via PHP, in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, user-permissions

In adding some js grids to an existing PHP application I ran into the following...

In one section of the site I need to display different content to different user roles. I can check for their role with a simple pre-built method n the PHP app, however I need to tell the JS side of things what the role is so it can display the correct content.

My first thought was to write the role to the dom in a hidden div and then retrieve it for use in JS:

```
<?php echo '<div id="user_role" style="display:none">5</div>'; ?>
```

then...

```
var user_role = $('#user_role').text();
```

But obviously this is not a good idea as anyone with access could manipulate the value in the dom and set it to whatever they like. So my question...

**What's the best way to set a user's role for use with javascript in this sort of situation?**

Comment: Definitely not by setting values at the client's side. The client is **evil**. Important data, such as whether a user has, say, administrative permissions, should be defined at the server's side. Your PHP script should always validate the user at each request by looking up permissions.

Comment: Where do you get that "different content" from?

Comment: @bazmegakapa - From the same database that the app uses. Essentially there are 5 types of user, each type will be shown a set of grids populated with data generated by the app that pertains to their role. Admins get to see all grids.

Comment: @lothar Then you can decide on the server side which data to send without receiving the role code from the client side. Adapt your display (Javascript) to the data you have been sent from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer here is anything on the client side in javascript a user can manipulate, so your best only showing your content specific to users on the server side with your php.

Also if you where to go down the route you where showing above you dont need to go through all that code you could simply use the code below no need to go round the houses adding it to the dom.

```
var user_role <?php echo(5); ?>
```

Comment: `var user_role=<?php echo json_encode($role) ?>;` for maximum safety. Even if the value would be an integer only, I always use json_encode - good habit to get into when dynamically generating javascript.

Comment: Good point marc I think the real point here is if you want a secure system you shouldnt set roles on the client side :)

Comment: No, simply don't send the user role to the client side. And don't ever send it back to the server and trust it.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with setting the user's role on client side as long as it's just for presentational purposes (like, changing the colours of the UI or hiding/showing certain containers), and changing the role on client side doesn't cause additional data to be shown.

It goes without saying that the *actual* setting of the user role - and any decisions what the user gets or doesn't get to see -  must take place on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could have JQuery ask the server at runtime what the role needs to be...

```
$.get('mysite/get_role.php', function(data) {
  var user_role = data;
  alert('User Role is ' + user_role);
});
```